# how to access array list in jsp , if i pass bean

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans

I am new to JSTL. How can i use JSTL `<c:foreach>` inside jsp if i pass below sample bean

```
class B{
    private String value="";
    private ArrayList arrayVals;
    public String getvalue(){
        return value;
    }
    public String getarrayVals(){
        return arrayVals;
    }
}
```

I will pass Bean "B" only.  I tried like below, but jsp not compiled. Please help me.

```
<c:forEach items="${B.getarrayVals}" var="book"> 
    <c:out value="{book.title}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 10):

First of all, `getarrayVals()` should be spelt `getArrayVals()`, and it should return a List, not a String, obviously.

Now suppose the servlet or action sets an attribute "b" of type B like this :

```
request.setAttribute("b", theBInstance);
```

and then forwards to a JSP, you can access the list in the attribute "b" like this:

```
${b.arrayVals}
```

You must refer to the B instance by the name of the request attribute, not by its class name. If you name the attribute foo, then use must use `${foo.arrayVals}`.
This will simply print to toString of the list. If you want to get the element at index 3 of the list, you can use

```
${b.arrayVals[3]}
```

And if you want to iterate over the list elements, use the c:forEach construct:

```
<c:forEach items="${b.arrayVals}" var="element">
    The element value is ${element} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```